# How can I schedule employee shifts with or-tools considering the required leave?

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I'm using CP-SAT solver, starting from this example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

To force the rest on weekends I entered this part of the code:

```
# Force weekends to OFF.
for e in range(num_employees):
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,5))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,6))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,12))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,13))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,19))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,20))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,26))
    fixed_assignments.append((e,0,27))
```

With the same method I can force a whole week of leave for a single employee, eliminating the constraint:

```
shift_constraints = [
    # One or two consecutive days of rest, this is a hard constraint.
    # (0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0), <-- removed
    # added to facilitate the assignment of the shifts for all the week
    # penalized but not hard to allow even rest days, otherwise the result         
    # would be NOT FEASIBLE
    (1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2), 
    (2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2), 
    (3, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 7), # <- night shift 
]
```

I also added this additional constraint to prevent the same employee from doing the same shift for two consecutive weeks:

```
weekly_sum_constraints = [
    # Constraints on rests per week.
    #(0, 1, 2, 7, 2, 3, 4),
    # At least 1 shift per week (penalized). At most 5 (hard).
    (1, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, -2),
    (2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, -2),
    (3, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 2),
]
# Penalized weeks transitions:
#     (previous_shift, next_shift, penalty (0 means forbidden))
penalized_weeks_transitions = [
    # Night to Night is forbidden.
    (3, 3, 0),
    (2, 2, 0),
    (1, 1, 0),
]
```

with the code:

```
# Penalized weeks transitions
for previous_shift, next_shift, cost in penalized_weeks_transitions:
    for e in range(num_employees):
        for d in range(num_days - 8):
            transition = [
                work[e, previous_shift, d].Not(),
                work[e, next_shift, d + 7].Not()
            ]
            if cost == 0:
                model.AddBoolOr(transition)
            else:
                trans_var = model.NewBoolVar(
                    'wtransition (employee=%i, day=%i)' % (e, d))
                transition.append(trans_var)
                model.AddBoolOr(transition)
                obj_bool_vars.append(trans_var)
                obj_bool_coeffs.append(cost)
```

In this way I can get the plan but, due to the constraint on requests to cover shifts:

```
weekly_cover_demands = [
    (14, 14, 7),  # Monday
    (14, 14, 7),  # Tuesday
    (14, 14, 7),  # Wednesday
    (14, 14, 7),  # Thursday
    (14, 14, 7),  # Friday
    (0, 0, 0),  # Saturday
    (0, 0, 0),  # Sunday
]
```

I can have some employees with rests within week especially if they have the night shift assigned. The logic therefore is: if you only need 7 people on the night shift, the other people in excess will receive the turn 0 (rest) so that the penalty for the night shift is reduced.

On the other hand, I would like to assign a valid shift in these cases, maybe Morning or Afternoon but not the rest shift.

So the question are:

1) What is the correct way to manage the employee when he is on vacation? Is it right to do it like I did forcing the turn to 0 (rest) as a hard constraint?

2) How can I write a constraint to ensure that night shifts are evenly distributed or, simpler perhaps, to ensure that there is only one week with night shift over the 4 weeks?

3) how can I avoid the automatic assignment of the rest shift if the night shift request is less than the availability of employees? (in this case the employees have to work anyway but in the morning or afternoon) ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First and foremost, you need to define the behavior of sum/span constraints with vacations in between.  This is complex. Then you can implement the right rules. I would add another type of shifts for Vacation. Maybe a solution is that a vacation shift could be used as some kind of joker.

Comment: Hi Laurent, thank you very much for the help. It seems to work but I still have a problem: I have inserted 2 days of leave for the worker 16 but the algorithm assigns him another 2 days of leave and one of rest. how can i send you the result, so to make you understand better?

Comment: Yes, for all non-leave day, you must force the 'leave' shift to be false.

Comment: Ok  Laurent, but the point is that I have no idea how to do it :-( could you please send me a snippet to help me figure out how I can force the shift to false?

Comment: model.Add(var == 0)

Comment: Hi Laurent, maybe you won't believe it but it works :) The point is that I don't know why. What I did was add another shift for leaves 'L' and another shift 'F' as Fake Shift, both without constraints and 0 as a weekly cover. If one worker is on leave for 1 to 4 days in the week, remaining days have shift 'F' assigned,  probably due to the constraints I have placed on the three shifts 'M','A','N' which force a minimum coverage of 5 and a maximum of 5 in the week. Moreover 'L' shift is allowed only on the days scheduled in the leave assignments list, as you suggested.